# Regex group don't get all the string

Tags: c#, regex

I created this Regex:

```
#define[\s]{1,}(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_$]){1,}[\s]{1,}(?<value>[a-zA-Z0-9_$\s()={},;.?:]){1,}
```

But when i test it this give me this result:

```
name: E
value: 6
```

String:

```
#define MAX_ARENE               10123456
```

How can i get all string in the group and not just the last char?

Anyway, if you need this is my C# code:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"#define[\s]{1,}([a-zA-Z0-9_$]){1,}[\s]{1,}([a-zA-Z0-9_$\s()={},;.]){1,}", RegexOptions.Singleline);

if (match.Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[1].ToString() + match.Groups[2].ToString());
    defines.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString(), match.Groups[2].ToString());
    node.Nodes.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString());
}
```

P.S Debug code.

I used this online tool http://regexhero.net/tester/ to test the Regex, but the same result happens in the MessageBox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're doing

```
(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_$]){1,}
```

you're repeating the capturing group *itself* (which matches a single character), thus overwriting each one-character match result with the next repetition. You want to use

```
(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)
```

Don't forget to do the same with `value`; also, `+` means "one or more", so use that instead of `{1,}`.

`[\s]` is superfluous as well - `\s` is enough.

Finally, I think it's more straightforward to use `match.Groups[n].Value` instead of `match.Groups[n].ToString()`.

Comment: `#define\s+(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)\s+(?<value>[a-zA-Z0-9_$\s()={},;.?:]+)` changed to this. Thanks now works ok. So if i do something like ([A-Z]){1,32} overwriting each one-character but if i do ([A-Z]{1,32}) is ok?

Comment: @MarcoLopezAcierno: Exactly.

Comment: Thanks! Exists a "fast way" to include all chars from A-Z to ~ - ^ ?

Comment: I means all chars possibile in a string instead of ([a-zA-Z0-9_$\s()={},;.?:""-^!~]+)

Comment: The dot matches any character except `\n`. So `(?<value>.+)` matches the entire (rest of the) string/line.